# Implementing complex data structures in C++

Tags: c++

What's the solution you adopt when you have to implement complex data structures in C++? I mean different kind of objects that should be referenced by other ones and, at the same time, reference other ones. It is really different from the available standard library containers.

Do you try to make your code very C++ and use generic programming (container style template)? IMHO, it seems hard to implement and inconvenient, and it could make the code harder to understand or to work with. Moreover, do you implement any kind of iterator?

Or maybe, on the other hand, you end up with "C style code"? I mean, in each class you implement a few pointers as member variables that reference other objects in order to build the suitable data structure.

According to your experience, what are the advantages and disadvantages of these two approaches? Any other solution?

Comment: Write C++ code with C++. Write C code with C. For a C++ developer with a reasonable amount of experience, those things you describe as hard to implement and inconvenient are actually very nice and understandable. It just takes learning, patience and practice.

Comment: No clearly correct answer. But in my view if you have a complex data structure then keep the interface simple and C++ like, and then if the implementation is messy and C like no one is going to care, as long as it's properly hidden.

Comment: Are you talking about implementing your own containers? What's the gain of doing so? Let's say that the data structure is far from being general, and only makes sense when it's used with your own classes.

Comment: Read "C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines and Best Practices." by Sutter and Alexandrescu and "Effective C++" by Meyers.

Comment: I should have a look at "Effective C++", I have wanted to read it for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of guidelines that I follow when writing complex data structures in C++:

1. Avoid raw pointers; use smart pointers.
2. Try to figure out early on if your data structure is cyclic or acyclic.  If there are cycles in your data structure you won't be able to used share_ptr everywhere without creating a leak.  At some point in your cyclic structure you want to break the cycle with a weak_ptr, so that objects can be released.
3. If my object holds onto other objects, and I want it to be a container, I implement the appropriate iterators *when I need them, and not one second before*.  I usually need iterator support when I want to use one of the STL algorithms on my container.  I could, of course, implement iterators that don't match the STL (in terms of naming or semantics) for my own use, but then I've added yet another way to do things in my code.  I try to avoid that.
4. If my class is intended to hold different types, then I use templates to express that.   There are ways to do this in C (using memcpy, etc), but while the code you'll end up with will be more understandable to C coders, you will lose most of the benefits of C++ (type safety, assignment operators, etc).

Comment: Thanks! The data structure is cyclic. I understand how shared_ptr objects can be very useful. But considering that I have to deal with many different kinds of pointers and cyclic structures, I see weak_ptr and shared_ptr as a mess. I prefer to take care of memory deallocation.

Comment: I understand how weak_ptr and shared_ptr could be seen as a mess, but while I've messed up memory allocation on my own plenty of times, shared_ptr and weak_ptr have never messed it up for me.

Comment: Regarding 4. the container is only intended to hold my own objects. It doesn't make sense at all for other classes. That's why it seemed to me that implementing it by means of member pointers (shared_ptr or raw) is the most straightforward solution.

Comment: On a semantic quibble, if your object doesn't have iterators then you shouldn't really even call it a "container" in the context of C++, which has appropriated the word to mean something that implements a specific interface. If you don't implement that interface then in C++ it's just a bunch of things ;-)

Comment: Good point about the container terminology. I've edited things to be what I hope is a bit more correct.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I shouldn't call it a container. Actually this was my initial question: does it make sense to implement a container in the context of C++ when you are sure it will be useful only for one purpose? It seems that, in this case, it isn't worth the trouble.